# Can I change the color of "Copy" bubble above UITextView and UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

When I am doing long touch on text in `UITextView` or in `UITextField`, a bubble appears with options "Cut, Copy, Paste":

[image]

Can I customize how it looks? For instance, can I change its background color (which is black by default) or text color (which is white by default)?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative can be [QBPopupMenu](https://github.com/questbeat/QBPopupMenu) as it's not possible with the public API.

You could customize it to appear as you like. You could then catch the system menu about to appear by listening to UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification notifications, hide it, and display the custom one instead.